# array_search returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, null

Help.

I have two tables in SQL (registrants and partners) and they each have several columns, but two columns with unique values (in the table), SequenceNo and Submission.  I'm trying to use either of these columns to find the matching row in the partners table.  All of this data was placed into the table by a form on the website.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<?PHP
$r = "regsandbox";
$p = "regsandboxpart";
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" .$r. "`ORDER BY `School` , `StudentLastName`";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->query();
$schoolrows = $db->loadAssocList();
$plena = sizeof($schoolrows);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" .$p. "`";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->query();
$partnerrows = $db->loadAssocList();
$plen = sizeof($partnerrows);

echo "<table>";
$school = null;
for ($i = 0; $i<sizeof($schoolrows); $i++) {
  $row = $schoolrows[$i];
  $group = $row ["Group"];
  $submission = $row["Submission"];
  $key = array_search($submission,$partnerrows);
  $partners = $partnerrows [$key];
  $lasta = $partners ["P1LastName"];
  $lastb = $partners ["P2LastName"];
  $firsta = $partners ["P1FirstName"];
```

The rest of the code is irrelevant, as $submission returns the correct needle, but when searching the haystack, the result is always null.

I'm new to php, so learning as I go, but I don't see why this doesn't work.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Post the results of using the function print_r() on the variables $submission and $partnerrows.

Comment: As usual: have you checked for errors? Are you sure that query don't fail? In addition: “array_search returns NULL” means that you have checked through `is_null( $key )` or simply that it doesn't have expected value?

Comment: @C.Lidell  Print_r() for $submissions returns all the Submission values (the print_r is running inside the for loop).  Example: OWSLA9CMJFPU03C1RLYE2DINEPWAPQA3XHLY2AM0OTKB4JZ27KDKRTH5VKGCQXRFJW3QNZB0PZYNENCG50...

Comment: @C.Liddell Print r for $partnerrows (371 rows and 20+ columns) contains lots of names and addresses of minors, so I include only the first few rows of results from where I tested the form entering the data into the table:  Array ( [0] => Array ( [SequenceNo] => 7214 [Submission] => 922F9LK3CP [Group] => No [ProjectTitle] => asdf [FirstName] => Mark [LastName] => Hobbs [P1LastName] => [P1FirstName] => [P1Address] => [P1City] => [P1Zip] => [P1Phone] => [P1Email] => [P1ParentFirst] => [P1ParentLast] => [P1ParentEmail] => [Paid1] => [Medical1] =>     ...

Comment: @fusion3k I've var_dump() every variable and they all return expected results.  $submission holds the correct value, but $key is 0.  $plen = sizeof($partnerrows);
$test = array_intersect($schoolrows,$partnerrows);
$long = sizeof($test);
var_dump($long);  $plen = 371, var_dump($long) outputs int(371).  And var_dump(is_null($key) outputs bool(false) for every $key in the loop.

Comment: if `var_dump( is_null( $key ) )` return False, `array_search` **doesn't** return `Null`. You say that `$key` return 0, that is the first item of `$partnerrows`. Try `var_dump( $key )` : I guess that its value is False, not 0: you are searching for a text value into a multidimensional aray.

Comment: @fusion3k I'm sorry, you are correct, var_dump($key) returns bool(false).  Yes, I am searching for text value into a multidimensional array... I thought that array_search was meant for?

Comment: `array_search` is for mono-dimensional array. If you want to search in a defined column and you have php >= 5.5, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635) about using `array_search` in multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Ok, I tried the following:    $subcolumn = array_column($partnerrows,'Submission');
var_dump($subcolumn);
$key = array_search($submission,$subcolumn);
$partners = $partnerrows [$key];  This crashes the code (specifically, the $subcolum = array_column... crashes the code).

Comment: @fusion3k Thank you!  I said I was new to php.  Nowhere that I have found does it say that array_search is not for a multi-dimensional array.  So I tried the following: $key = array_search($submission, array_column($partnerrows,'Submission'));  But this crashes the page when it reaches the line.  Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkHobbs and it works for you?

Comment: @fusion3k Perhaps I should change the title to array_column crashes my code.  I did a var_dump($partnerrows) and show the first few rows below.  The array contains the field "Submission", so I'm at a loss again. :( array(371) { [0]=> array(32) { ["SequenceNo"]=> string(4) "7214" ["Submission"]=> string(10) "922F9LK3CP" ["Group"]=> string(2) "No" ["ProjectTitle"]=> string(4) "asdf" ["FirstName"]=> string(4) "Mark" ["LastName"]=> string(5) "Hobbs" ["P1LastName"]=> string(0) "" ["P1FirstName"]=> string(0) "" ["P1Address"]=> string(0) "" ["P1City"]=> string(0) "" ["P1Zip"]=> string(0) ""

Comment: Your  php version? (Also see the apache error log to isolate the error)

Comment: php was version 5.4, but updated to 5.5 and now the function works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

```
$submission = $row["Submission"];
$key = array_search($submission,$partnerrows);
```

`$partnerrows` is a multi-dimensional array, so your search fails.

To search for a key into a multi-dimensional array you can use:

#### On PHP version >= 5.5:

```
$key = array_search( $submission, array_column( $partnerrows, 'Submission' ) );
```

#### On PHP version < 5.5<sup>1</sup>:

```
if( !function_exists( 'array_column' ) )
{
    function array_column( array $input, $column_key, $index_key = null )
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach( $input as $k => $v )
        {
            $result[ $index_key ? $v[ $index_key ] : $k ] = $v[ $column_key ];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$key = array_search( $submission, array_column( $partnerrows, 'Submission' ) );
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Original code from https://gist.github.com/TorbenKoehn/5866154

Comment: Question: won't the _if_ evaluate to _false_ and not execute the statement.  Shouldn't it be:  `if(!function_exists('array_column')) {  } else {  function array_column ...`

Comment: @MarkHobbs No. if the function does not exist (php<5.5) we create it, else we do nothing (the function already exists). This is a standard way to ensure backward compatibility.